# Svelte error localStorage is not defined

Tags: javascript, svelte

Soy nuevo en `svelte` y estoy teniendo un problema en recuperar un `token` que almacene en el `localStorage`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual intento recuperar de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado investigando, pero no encuentro que da ese error o no se si lo estoy haciendo de una manera incorrecta.

Comment: El error te dice que `localStorage`no está definido en ese contexto

Comment: Hola Miguel, puede que [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216597/3791844) te sea de ayuda. Recordá que si logras solucionarlo podes responder a tu pregunta. Compartir la solución puede ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Saludos!

Comment: si me dice que no es definido

Comment: Lo más probable es que ese componente se esté llamando del lado del servidor, por lo que no encontrará el localStorage